# Filtering Rows matching String condition in R

Tags: r, string, filter

I`ve got some problems filtering for duplicate elements in a string. My data look similar to this:

```
idvisit     path
1           1,16,23,59,16
2           2,14,19,14
3           5,19,23
4           10,21
5           23,27,29,23
```

I have a column containing an unique ID and a column containing a path for web page navigation. The right column contains some cases, where pages  were accessed twice or more often, but some different pages are between these accesses. I just want to filter() the rows, where pages occur twice or more often and at least one page is in bettween the two accesses, so the data should look like this.

```
idvisit     path
1           1,16,23,59,16
2           2,14,19,14
5           23,27,29,23
```

I just want to remove the rows that match the conditions. I really dont know how to handle a String with using a variable for the many different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter based on the number of elements in each string. Strings with duplicated entries will be larger than their unique lengths, i.e.

```
df1[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$path), ','), function(i) length(unique(i)) != length(i)),]
#  idvisit          path
#1       1 1,16,23,59,16
#2       2    2,14,19,14
#5       5   23,27,29,23
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thanks a lot :) Do you have any useful link, that i can learn more about this string-stuff by myself? i searched the web a lot but did not find any useful hints for my problem?

Comment: Well, most of waht I learned, I learned from here to be honest

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
lst <- strsplit(df1$path, ",")
df1[lengths(lst) != sapply(lst, uniqueN),]
#  idvisit          path
#1       1 1,16,23,59,16
#2       2    2,14,19,14
#5       5   23,27,29,23
```

---

Or an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
separate_rows(df1, path) %>% 
     group_by(idvisit) %>% 
     filter(n_distinct(path) != n()) %>% 
     summarise(path = toString(path))
```

Comment: That doesn't take care of the situation when there is same page twice, but no other page in between

Comment: @ira Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You could try regular expressions too with `grepl`:

```
df[grepl('.*([0-9]+),.*,\\1', as.character(df$path)),]
#  idvisit          path
#1       1 1,16,23,59,16
#2       2    2,14,19,14
#5       5   23,27,29,23
```